# meteor template on mobile safari will not display my return

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, meteor

I'm trying to show on screen in mobile safari my return from my Template function.
I can see that my device supports devicemotion
I can see a console log of my var tiltFB with the data

What I can't see or get to work is it showing up on screen in my html on mobile safari.

```
Template.tapapp.showAngle = function() {

var tiltFB;

if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', deviceMotionHandler, false);
  console.log("Devicemotion IS supported on your device.");
} else {

  console.log("Devicemotion Not supported on your device.");
  return "Devicemotion Not supported on your device.";
}

function deviceMotionHandler(eventData) {

  var acceleration = eventData.accelerationIncludingGravity;
  var rawAcceleration = "[" +  Math.round(acceleration.x) + ", " +     Math.round(acceleration.y) + ", " + Math.round(acceleration.z) + "]";

  var facingUp = -1;
  if (acceleration.z > 0) {
    facingUp = +1;
  }

  tiltFB = Math.round(((acceleration.y + 9.81) / 9.81) * 90 * facingUp);

  console.log(tiltFB);

  //Meteor.defer(function () {
  //     $('#angel').html(tiltFB);
  //     return tiltFB;
  });
  return tiltFB;
}

};
```

here is my html:

```
<template name="tapapp">
  <div class="container">
  <h3 class="angel-class" id="angle">{{showAngle}}</h3>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need to return a value in your `showAngle` helper, and hook it up reactively via Session.set/get

Client js

```
function deviceMotionHandler(eventData) {

  var acceleration = eventData.accelerationIncludingGravity;
  var rawAcceleration = "[" +  Math.round(acceleration.x) + ", " +     Math.round(acceleration.y) + ", " + Math.round(acceleration.z) + "]";

  var facingUp = -1;
  if (acceleration.z > 0) {
    facingUp = +1;
  }

  tiltFB = Math.round(((acceleration.y + 9.81) / 9.81) * 90 * facingUp);

  console.log(tiltFB);

  //Meteor.defer(function () {
  //     $('#angel').html(tiltFB);
  //     return tiltFB;
  //});
  Session.set("tiltFB", tiltFB);
}


Template.tapapp.showAngle = function() {
    return Session.get("tiltFB");
}

Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
        window.addEventListener('devicemotion', deviceMotionHandler, false);
        console.log("Devicemotion IS supported on your device.");
    } else {
        console.log("Devicemotion Not supported on your device.");
    }
});
```